# Prolog : last element

Tags: prolog

So I am writing a predicate and part of it is to check if 2 two lists have the same tail.
I know, there is a `last\2` but I tried this one as well but it failed and I suspect it's because of this part of code:
`check([H|_,T],[Y|,_,U]):- T = U`
It raises an error message:  `unexpected comma or bar at the of list`

Is there an other way around?

Comment: Your list syntax is wrong. `[H | T]` is correct and so is `[H1, H2 | T]`. The element after the bar must be a list. I'm not sure what you are trying to write but at least `[H | [_, T]]` or `[H, _ | T]` will clear syntax check.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using `last/2` but if you want to explicitly iterate you can do the following.
The predicate uses four clauses.

1. If they have one element each,
2. If they are both lists of more than two elements,
3. and 4. When one of the list lengths reach one.

```
ctail([H], [H]).
ctail([_, H1|T1], [_, H2|T2]) :-
    ctail([H1|T1], [H2|T2]).
ctail([H1], [_, H2|T2]) :-
    ctail([H1], [H2|T2]).
ctail([_, H1|T1], [H2]) :-
    ctail([H1|T1], [H2]).
```

```
?- ctail([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [a, b, c, d]).
false.

?- ctail([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [a, b, c, d, 5]).
true
```